# Custom Condition Price Rules

Tags: magento-1.9

Google sends parameters like `utm_source`, `utm_campaign`, etc ... I would like to know how I get these parameters in magento because I would like to add a custom condition in price rules, check if `utm_source is = partner` if yes, apply discount.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know how he is your URL and that parameters ! in Magento standard URL's are formated like this: `http://domain.com/rooter/controllerName/actionMethod`.

1. If your URL is like this: `http://domain.com/path/index/id/bling/123456`, you can get the bling paramater as follow: `$this->getRequest()->getParam('bling') //you get 123456`.
2. If your Url is like this: `http://domain.com/index?bling=123456`, you get the bling parametrer as follow: `$_GET['bling'] // you get 123456`.
3. You can get all the params in array like this: `$this->getRequest()->getParams()`.

Once you have you parameter, you can do some conditions to apply your disount.

**Exemple:**

```
if ( $this->getRequest()->getParam('utm_source') == 'partner' ){
    //your discount here
}

if ( $_GET['utm_source'] == 'partner' ){
    //your discount here
}
```